# Two ways to use Spring 3 validation?

Tags: spring, validation, spring-3

I want to use Spring 3 for validation.

In the reference documentation, section 6.2 deals with the `Validator` interface that we may implement for the classes we want to validate. It's explained how to create the `Validator` class but not how to validate objects.

Section 6.7 deals with the use of `JSR-303` API and the annotations that come with. It seems that it's a different way to validate objects (in this case, using annotations without creating `Validator` classes).

Are there really two ways to use Spring validation or I'm missing something?

One simple question, it's also specified that an implementation of `JSR-303` API must be present on the classpath. One proposed implementation is `Hibernate-Validator`. Does Spring provide an implementation?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there are two ways:

- Validator Interfaces are the old one, mainly used in spring 2
- JSR 303 is new, It does not exist while spring 2 was build

I would recommend to use JSR 303. - In my opinion there is only one reason to use the old validators: that is if you need a LOT of cross field validations, because they are relative hard to implement with JSR 303 (but its is possible)

To use JSR 303 you need to add an validator implementation, for example Hibernate-Validator (it is the default implementation of JSR 303) (Hibernate-Validator is NOT the Hibernate ORM!, it is only related)

This is a bit like JPA, there is the common neutral specification (javax.jpa/javax.validation) and the different provider implementations (for JPA for example: EclipseLink or Hibernate)

---

This is an example how to test a validation (the goal of the test was to test the validation itself, but I changed the Validator to a common one), anyway it should show you how to test a validator:

```
public class NotEmptyTest {

    public static class Demo {

        @NotEmpty
        String string;

        public Demo(final String string) {
            this.string = string;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testNotEmptysWithValid() {
        /** given: a valid object */
        Demo valid = new Demo("hallo Welt");

        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        Validator validator = factory.getValidator();

        /** then there must not be any constraint violations */
        AssertUtil.isEmpty(validator.validate(valid));
    }

    @Test
    public void testNotEmptyInValid() {
        /** given: an invalid object */
        Demo valid = new Demo("");

        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        Validator validator = factory.getValidator();

        /** then there must not be one constraint violation */
        Set<ConstraintViolation<Demo>> result = validator.validate(valid);

        AssertUtil.hasSize(1, result);
        ConstraintViolation<Demo> firstItem = result.iterator().next();
        Assert.assertEquals("{org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty.message}",
                firstItem.getMessageTemplate());
    }
}
```

But in an Spring MVC Controller it is much easier, you only need to add `@Valid` to your command object parameter and need to add a `BindingResult` parameter directly after the command object parameter

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView create(@Valid UserCreateCommand userCreateCommand,
         BindingResult bindingResult) {

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        //show form again
    } else {
        //create user and 
        //redirect To Show user
    }
}
```

And the UserCreateCommand is just a POJO where the fields are annotated with a lot of JSR303 Validation constraints.

```
public class UserCreateCommand {

    @Length(min = 2)
    @NotBlank
    private String login;

    @Email
    @NotNull
    private String emailAddress;

    ....

    //GETTER and SETTER
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you provide a simple example with one domain class and its corresponding unit test? I would want to know how to setup Spring to validate this class. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Thanks for the example. In the NotEmptyTestClass, you could declare the LocalValidatorFactoryBean in the application context, am I right? Then, I need to obtain a Validator from this ValidatorFactory. And then, if I call the validate method on a UserCreateCommand instance, the latter is validated according to the JSR-303 annotations put on it? (I'm not using MVC so I don't know how it works in a general case).

Comment: I do not 100% understand the last comment. But the test works without Spring (this mean: no spring context)!  On the other hand it should be possible to inject the Validator into any Spring Bean. The important point is "Spring Bean" not every class is a spring bean. In my example is the Controller the only one Spring Bean. (May you should have a look at "@Configurable").

Comment: Following the example you provided, assume UserCreateCommand is one of my domain classes. It is annotated with the JSR-303 annotations. I wanted to know how to validate this class? I understood from your example that to validate the class I need to call the validate method of a Validator (previously obtained using a ValidatorFactory - e.g. LocalValidatorFactoryBean). Am I right?

Comment: Yes. -- The only problem you have to solve, if you want that this class is validation itself, is to make it a spring bean. -- That is why I give you the hint with `@Configurable`

Answer (score 0):

```
We can use two level of validation in spring 

1.)using annotation 
2.)using properties file

in .jsp
--------------

<style type="text/css">
.errors {
    color: red;
}


.errorblock {
    color: #000;
    background-color: #ffEEEE;
    border: 3px solid #ff0000;
    padding: 8px;
    margin: 16px;
}

</style>


<c:url value="saveUser" var="saveUser"/>
<form:form action="${saveUser}" method="post" commandName="user">
<table>
<form:errors path="*" cssClass="errorblock" element="div"></form:errors> 
<tr>
<td>User Id:</td>
<td><form:input path="userId"/>
<form:errors path="userId" cssClass="errors"></form:errors>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password:</td>
                <td><form:password path="password" />
                <form:errors path="password" cssClass="errors"></form:errors>
</td>
</tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='2'><input name="submit" type="submit"
                    value="submit" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='2'><input name="reset" type="reset" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</form:form>


User.java
----------------------------

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;


public class User {
    @NotEmpty(message="UserId is Required")
    private String userId;
        @NotEmpty
    private String password;
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

}

UserController.java
--------------------

@RequestMapping(value="/saveUser" ,method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveUser(@Valid @ModelAttribute User user,BindingResult bindingResult)
{
    System.out.println("in register"+user.getPassword());
    if(bindingResult.hasErrors())
    {
    return "register";
    }
    return "login";
}

in dispatcher-servlet.xml
--------------------------
<bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames">
        <list>
                <value>message</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean> 

message.properties(put this file in classpath)
---------------------
NotEmpty.user.password = password is required!
```